# Biber can't find UTF-8 named files

Tags: biblatex, biber

It seems that `biber` is not able to deal with UTF-8 named files as in the following MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{produção.bib}
@article{Kantorovich-1958,
   author = {Leonid Kantorovich},
   title = {On the translocation of masses},
   journal = {Management Science},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\addbibresource{produção.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Kantorovich-1958}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

When executing `latex` and then `biber` on Linux TL 2022, I get:

```
INFO - Globbing data source 'produção.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'produção.bib' to producÌ§aÌo.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'producÌ§aÌo.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Cannot find 'produção.bib'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

I also noticied that in the production of the error message, a different UTF-8 sequence is used for the letter `ã`, one that has a higher up tilde on top of the `a`, as one can see here:

[image: biber looking for the wrong file]

In fact, if I try to list them:

```
$ ls produção.bib
ls: cannot access 'produção.bib': No such file or directory
$ ls prod*
produção.bib
```

Anyone knows what is going on and how one can deal with it?

Comment: it works ok on windows + texlive 2023.

Comment: Would it greatly inconvenience you to name the file `producao.bib`, i.e., from using only ascii-encoded characters?

Comment: @Mico Yes, it will not only be greatly incovenient, but also impossible at the moment. I produced the MWE using the character at the file name, just to show the problem, but in my real case the character causing the problem is at the PATH -- one that I have no control. The problem is the same if the character is not present at the filename, but in the path to it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that is weird that this things works better in MS Windows.

Comment: @DaiBowen The filename is produced by the code, which is fully in UTF-8. The filename is entered twice in the code and they are exactly the same thing. As you ca see from the `ls` the file is created fine and it is there -- but it is never seen by `biber`.

Comment: @TeXApprentice Sorry, was focusing on the log and ls, can you check which characters are used for the file name in the `.bcf` file?  Might need more info about your system, all works for me fedora/bash/vanilla texlive 2022&2023.

Comment: @DaiBowen the filename of the `.bcf` file only depends on what you name your example file -- and not the `.bib` file. In my case I named it `b1.tex` and I naturally got `b1.bcf` which is independet of the name given to the `.bib`.

I am doing this on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 with TL 22.

Comment: @TeXApprentice *inside* the `.bcf` file you will have a line (you will need to ctrl+f) something like `<bcf:datasource type="file" datatype="bibtex" glob="false">produção.bib</bcf:datasource> `, this is what `biber` uses to know what `.bib` file(s) to look for, it's worth checking which sequences are written there.

Comment: @DaiBowen thanks for clarifying. I found the line now. It has the correct set of characters, just as I have entered it on the MWE file above. I can Ctl-C, Ctl-V nd I can see the file fine with `ls`. Bit there is something -- that I have never see before -- running the command `file b1.bcf` I get as an answer `b1.bcf: XML 1.0 document, ASCII text` whic is NOT really what I would expect to see.

Comment: @TeXApprentice I see the same, I think it's fine, `file` is just missing the (very few) non-ASCII characters when trying to infer encoding. Can you confirm `locale` gives you UTF-8 and what `biber --version` is?

Comment: @Mico While in the short term using the workaround is an option, in the long term it's rather unreasonable to expect the users to apply workaround to accommodate the software bug instead of fixing the software. (unless some hard backward compatibility is needed like the case of TeX itself but that's not the case here)

Comment: I think this issue is already covered in https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/310

Comment: This works for me both on Windows (fully updated MikTeX, Biber 2.19) and Linux (Ubuntu 18.04, with up-to-date vanilla TeX Live 2023 installed from TUG, Biber 2.19). I'm guessing when you say "Linux TL 2022" you mean the TeX Live you get from your Linux distribution and not the TUG one. Can you tell us which Biber version you are using (`biber --version`). What are your locale settings (what does `locale` output)?

Comment: The issue https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/310 might be relevant, but it is also pretty old. A system with TeX Live 2022 should have at least Biber 2.17. This was about versions 2.14 and below. So please, double check your Biber version. As for the warning messages showing the wrong characters, I think this is related to https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/444, which will be fixed in Biber 2.20.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce on a fresh ubuntu 22.04 vm with `apt`'s TL 2022 (biber 2.17), setting `locale` to `POSIX` didn't seem to do it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help with this one. The problem was an older version of `biber` installed by TL from Ubuntu repository.  After reinstallation of everything I still have one minor problem: The 6th and 8th lines of message of the command `biber filename` end up reporting two diffrent versions for the name of the bibtex database file. The 6th line reports a version of the name that has a different c-cedilla and a different a-tilda than reported on the 8th line.

Comment: That sounds like it would be https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/444, which will be fixed in a future version of Biber (2.20). The version of the file name as written in the log output has no influence on which file is used, though. So this should hopefully be mostly a cosmetic thing.

Comment: It is sligthly more than just a cosmetic issue because one frequently copy & paste out of it. I am glad it is coming to an end soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments your main issue is https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/310, which occurred in Biber 2.14 and was fixed in version 2.15 (released in August 2020). A reasonably recent system should no longer have this issue, because Biber should not attempt to glob file names without you telling it to. Make sure you have a reasonably current TeX system installed.

The wrong version (NFC vs NFD) of the file name in the log output is looks similar to https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/444. A fix was committed not too long ago. It will be in the next release of Biber (most like called 2.20). Hopefully this also resolves your problem. For now this should be only a cosmetic thing. Internally, the right file is found.